# Counterexample for Every $\sigma$-finite measure is semifinite.

Tags: measure-theory

Every $\sigma$-finite measure is semifinite. 
The converse is in general not true, thus I'm looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of semifinite is that, every $A\in\mathcal{M}$ satisfies that 
\begin{align*}
\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(B): B\in\mathcal{M}, B\subseteq A, \mu(B)<\infty\}.
\end{align*}
Consider the counting measure on an uncountable set $X$. This is semifinite as the way how we define the sum for uncountable index.

It is not $\sigma$-finite, because for any countable union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}X_{n}=X$, some $X_{n}$ is uncountable, and is of infinite measure of course.

Comment: @StigPesälä you definitely should have, I gave the vote to this answer almost solely for turning your question into one that can be answered (by giving the definition)